NDepend query should not return methods like ToString or ToInt32
I am struggling with a simple NDepend query that should return all methods that are not called by any other method (dead code) but not methods with names like ToString() or ToInt32().
The following query returns method names like ToString(), ToChar() or ToInt32() which should be excluded because their name starts with "To" due to this condition:
&& !m.SimpleName.StartsWith("To*")
// <Name>Methods that are not called</Name>
// <Description>Shows all Methods that could be removed</Description>
from m in JustMyCode.Methods
where m.NbMethodsCallingMe == 0
 && !m.IsConstructor
 && !m.IsAbstract
 && !m.SimpleName.StartsWith("get_")
 && !m.SimpleName.StartsWith("set_")
 && !m.SimpleName.StartsWith("<>f")
 && !m.SimpleName.Contains("callback")
 && !m.SimpleName.Contains("TClient")
 && !m.SimpleName.StartsWith("To*")
 && !m.SimpleName.StartsWith("From*")
 && !m.SimpleName.Contains("Click")
 && m.SimpleName != "BeginInvoke"
 && m.SimpleName != "EndInvoke"
 && m.SimpleName != ".cctor"
select new { m, MethodName = m.SimpleName, Count= m.NbMethodsCallingMe}

What I am missing?

You don't need to specify a wildcard when calling StartsWith on a string. You don't have any methods that start with a T, an o and then literally an asterisk character.

Silly me (I know StartsWith for allmost 20 years)
